# "sudo snap install android-studio --classic" trying to install android studio I got the following error:

Tags: command-line, apt

Error: cannot perform the following tasks: `Download snap "android-studio" (70) from channel "stable" (stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR)`

Answer (score 1):

It is connection problem. You need to have good internet connection.
Please try it again after you connected to a good network.